# How do I "share" a socket between a thread and a function?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get user input from stdin whilst receiving data from a socket. Then I want to send the user input to the socket. How can I pass the socket to a thread that is able to send and read whilst having the main function reading from stdin and sending it to the socket. This function does not need to be able to read from the socket. 
I would prefer being able to use a BufferedStream as my socket reader. 
Thread receives and sends -(while)- function gets input from stdin and sends to socket.

Comment: Why do you need to share the socket between the threads? Could you get away with just transferring the read lines between threads?

Comment: @Shepmaster     
 
In reality I'm just trying to share a socket between a thread and a function. Could I just share the ownership of the socket using an Arc?

Comment: I have a working example. I just made a thread for each function and passed the sockets. Seems to work fairly well. :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're actually doing with the socket and the standard input and how you interleave them.

The cleanest way is to use channels to pass the data between threads:

```
use std::old_io as io;
use std::old_io::net::tcp::TcpStream;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread::Thread;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<Vec<u8>>();
    let g = Thread::scoped(move || {
        let mut s = TcpStream::connect("example.com:80").unwrap();
        println!("> Opened connection, waiting for input");
        let query = rx.recv().unwrap();
        s.write(&query).unwrap();
        s.close_write();

        let r = String::from_utf8(s.read_to_end().unwrap()).unwrap();
        println!("Response:\n{}", r);
    });

    let mut data = Vec::new();
    for line in io::stdin().lock().lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        if line.trim().is_empty() { break; }
        data.push_all(line.trim().as_bytes());
        data.push_all(b"\r\n");
    }
    data.push_all(b"\r\n");
    tx.send(data).unwrap();

    println!("Waiting for response...");
}
```

There is a [`clone()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/old_io/net/tcp/struct.TcpStream.html#method.clone) method on `TcpStream` which "splits" the socket into two. You can pass them into different threads. Consider using channels first, however.